# replace using sed

Tags: linux, shell, sed, redhat

I want to replace IP dynamically but somehwo sed is placing word $IP instead of actual value.

```
 IP=10.50.33.44
 PORT=5774
 sed -i~ 's/https:\/\/10.11.12.13:8443/https:\/\/$IP:$PORT/g' abc.txt
```

Can you help me out in getting the correct value?

Comment: A little tip: If you don't want to escape the `/` character, you can use something like `s%<pattern>%<replacement>%`. The `/` or `%` character can of course be something else not found in the pattern or replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes`"` for variable expansion:

```
 sed -i~ "s/https:\/\/10.11.12.13:8443/https:\/\/$IP:$PORT/g" abc.txt
```

and as [@Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) said, use different delimiter. For example,

```
 sed -i~ "s;https://10.11.12.13:8443;https://$IP:$PORT;g" abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on a theme: I always use single quotes to surround sed/awk/perl... commands as the shell can sometimes trip you up when using double quotes.
I find it best to double quote the variables:

```
sed -i~ 's/https:\/\/10.11.12.13:8443/https:\/\/'"$IP"':'"$PORT"'/g' abc.txt
```

As a "belt and braces" and as I usually compose my commands interactively at the command line in bash, the key-binding M-C-e (that's Alt-Control-e on most keyboards) will interpolate the command before it's sent. Letting you visually see what the command is really getting.